# Ubuntu Snap vscode error trying to use java JDK

Tags: java, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am relearning Java and I am using VSCode as my regular IDE on Kubuntu 20.04.  I love it for python and some other languages but I have a problem with Java.

I get the following error when I open a .java file in the VSCode IDE;

> Sorry, Something went wrong activating Intellicode support for Java

and

> Java 11 or more recent is required to run the Java extension. Please download and install .....

Now I can compile my simple Java program on the command line and run it without error;

```
$ javac HelloWorld.java
$ java HelloWorld
Hello, World!
$
```

I've googled this for over a month and I see others with this problem but I don't see solutions.  What I have learned is the Snap system won't let programs go outside the $HOME folder and my Java home folder is in /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/.

How can I configure Snap to allow VSCode to see Java in that folder?  Should I just copy the Java JDK to my $HOME folder?

**Edit:**  I tried using a soft link with the following commands;

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 /home/jc/dev/java11
```

and changed the VSCode settings.json with the following;

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
      {
        "name": "JavaSE-11",
        "path": "/home/jc/dev/java11"
       },

]
```

It didn't seem to make the error go away.  I also tried changing the config file to point right at ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 but no luck.

**Edit 2:** I also tried copying the JDK folders to my home folder and it didn't not take either.

Comment: Have you tried to make a symlink in a space that is available to snap and pointing your path over there?

Comment: No luck.  I create a link with the command ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 /home/jc/dev/java11.  I edited vscode config file with the following addition; "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "/home/jc/dev/java8",
            "default":  true
          },
          {
            "name": "JavaSE-11",
            "path": "/home/jc/dev/java11"
           },
    
    ]  But no luck